# Как работать с хешем в Url?

Tags: javascript, url, хеширование

Есть страница, изначально с обычным Url. Затем пользователь кликает кнопки, чекбоксы и меняются их значения, потом жмёт- Поиск и аяксом идёт запрос.

Хочу сделать, чтоб когда он изменяет элементы, менялся Url, чтоб потом можно было откатиться к этому Url.

Когда-то делал на ангуляр-роутинге, но в этом сайте jquery - есть ли вариант на простом джаваскрипте?

Как сделать Url типа mysite.com/search#param1=1&param2=2 ...? И после перехода по этой ссылке восстановить все выбранные элементы.

Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string вот интересная библиотечка для работы с queryString в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

При инициализации страницы парсите window.location.hash и в зависимости от параметров в хеше устанавливаете выбранные элементы (с помощью jQuery). По-другому никак.

Comment: А как все элементы конкретного div-а засунуть в хеш строку? и соответственно потом распарсить её?

Comment: я не знаю сколько у вас элементов, какие они могут принимать значения-состояния :-) Формат записи в хеш может быть самым разным. В том числе JSON.

Comment: Я сделал var str = $("form").serialize(); window.location.hash = str; Вот только когда по ссылке переходишь- как восстановить элементы из хеша?

Comment: Лучше вот так:
window.location.hash = '#' + str;

т.е. впереди добавить решётку.


Чтобы восстановить элементы - распарсиваете строку, получаете отдельные параметы (split по символу '&', затем для каждого куска split по символу '=', затем декодирование полученных значений) и устанавливаете значения каждого элемента $('*[name="' + parsedParameterName + '"]', "form").val( parsedParameterValue)